# Splitting multiple rows into multiple columns without the use of VBA

Tags: excel

I know there's already questions and answers out there regarding what I'm asking today but they are to specific to the person who's asking the questions and I can't use the answers for my question...

I have a database that goes like this:

```
   A

1  Name

2  Email

3  Name

4  Email
```

But I need it to go like this

```
...A..................B

Name..........Email
```

(IGNORE FULL STOPS)

How can I do this without using a VBA but rather a shortcut of some sort?

Comment: To clarify, do you want row 1 to go Name...Email...Name...Email, or do you want column A to have the names and column B to have the Email? If you want the latter and have no spaces in your datablock then Gary's solution below should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
CTRL + C
ALT then H then V then S then E.
```

This is the keyboard command to copy a range of values and paste them in a Transposition (shift the X axis and Y axis).

Comment: Did nothing. Got a VBA instead?

Comment: I know I said no VBA but I understand them better so

Comment: If you are unable to copy and paste it is not advisable to use VBA code you pulled from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2-1)
```

and copy down.  In **C1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROW()*2)
```

and copy down:

[image]